# Record screen section as animated GIF

Tags: linux, osx, gratis, screen-recording

Often while trying to explain a problem I have with my PC, a screenshot is not enough.

Is there a tool that lets you capture a section of the screen and save it to a .gif file?

It needs to

- Work on Ubuntu and Mac.
- Let you capture a section of the screen not just all of the screen.
- Be free.

Comment: Do it has to be directly to a gif? Couldn't be to Video and you can later make the conversion?

Comment: @Braiam i could do  that but it would be more convenient if it recorded to gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but..

[Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) is a little open source program designed for doing exactly this. It has packages in most major linux distributions, though I don't know about OS X support.

Comment: This is awesome. Just what I wanted when I asked the question.

Answer (score 19):

For a Mac (and Windows) solution, you can try [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

> LICEcap can capture an area of your desktop and save it directly to .GIF (for viewing in web browsers, etc).

Features:

- Move the screen capture frame while recording.
- Pause and restart recording, with optional inserted text messages.
- Global hotkey (shift+space) to toggle pausing while recording
- Adjustable maximum recording framerate, to allow throttling CPU usage.
- Basic title frame, with or without text.
- Record mouse button presses.
- Display elapsed time in the recording.

Here is a GIF demonstrating the apps usage on Windows

[image: LICEcap Demo]

Comment: Licecap is simply the best option if you want to do it on mac or windows. I have a much better [screencap in my question here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/710/linux-based-alternative-to-licecap) that shows how it works. Feel free to use it if you wish ;)/

Comment: Is it working on Ubuntu?

Comment: No this does not work on Ubuntu unfortunately. I am still looking for one since I would like one as well.

Comment: An rudimentary screen recording app you can find at [Linux-based alternative to LICEcap](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/710/linux-based-alternative-to-licecap/741#741), there is SimpleScreenRecorder too but so far I weren’t able to run it on Ubuntu, so wont suggest an app I couldn’t test or use myself.

Comment: Update: LICEcap works fine in wine

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for **Free**, but ...

The Snagit tool from Techsmith (http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) has what you need AND a whole lot more for other tasks you have not asked about. I have used this tool for multiple years for multiple purposes: the use-case you describe, creating training videos, annotating defects in software (QA support), creating web elements and much more.

There is a free trial that may get you over your immediate problem (if it is a "one shot" thing, rather than something you are going to be doing often during the next year.

Comment: Does it work on Ubuntu or Mac?

Comment: Techsmiths Snagit does run on Mac.

Comment: Reason been I'm asking it is that main feature requested is to work on **Ubuntu** and **Mac**. Snagit is mainly windows tool..

Comment: Snagit has added a lightweight way to work on Ubuntu also -- as a Chrome browser addon -- see this description.[link](http://blogs.techsmith.com/news-events/snagit-for-linux/#.UvaR7vmIC-0)

Comment: Excellent didn’t know Chrome extension of Snagit play nice with Ubuntu. Upvoted

Answer (score 1):

For OS X:

[This](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/4627207) is a tutorial on how to record with QuickTime and then convert to GIF using ffmpeg.  `ffmpeg` is quick and easy to install using e.g. MacPorts (`sudo port install ffmpeg`).

Comment: tldr - install ffmpeg and gifcicle using brew, record with quicktimethen use the command `ffmpeg -i in.mov -s 600x400 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -f gif - | gifsicle --optimize=3 --delay=3 > out.gif` to convert.