# Record screen to animated GIF on Linux (alternative to LICEcap)

Tags: linux, screen-recording, gif

I use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) fairly extensively when answering questions on Stack Exchange - its a VERY intuitive tool for making gif-based screen captures

[image: LINEcap gif example]

You open the application, select an area to record, choose a filename to save it, and do your thing so it can record.

However, this is Windows and OS X only - I've occasionally toyed with using a Linux VM and capturing the VM window, but I'd like a *native* alternative that would record a gif the same way.

What could I use?

Comment: Would you like other animated images as well or is the file format "gif" a necessary requirement?

Comment: Well, I don't really want/need *video*. Gif's the 'accepted' standard for animated images. If its something that *should* work universally, it would be ok, but I can't think of any other format that would be a suitable replacement

Comment: MNG (extension of PNG) does this.

Comment: oh, if its something I can shove into an internet facing server, and open on a browser I'm fine.

Comment: As an aside, licecap runs on wine perfectly well, much to my surprise. Of course, this is limited to x86 boxen, has a fairly large set of dependencies and so on, but its what I think I'll be using for now. The selected answer would do the trick, but it lacks the elegance the licecap UI has.

Comment: I would suggest [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php), which has builds for various Linux distros. The problem with it is that it seems to only record to the ogv format - though converting to a GIF can be done using ffmpeg/imagemagick (explained [here](http://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality)). recordMyDesktop has frontends which are easy to use - you set where to save the file and options such as following the mouse and what to record first, then hit record.

Comment: I always used it under wine, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Update 10/22/2014: Seth Johnson has improved the Ubuntu PPA so that only the Silentcast PPA is required. (Previously, 3 PPA's were needed.)

Update 10/13/2014: Version 2.0 released. Added options to create webm or mp4 videos instead of just animated gifs. Added a script to do a full install without root privileges.

Update 10/4/2014: Runs in Unity, no problem, and there's now a PPA for installation - Thanks to [Seth](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/86/seth) for his Unity Indicator patch and PPA. Please have a look at the installation instructions below which I've updated today. Also, **you can run it without installing it**. Follow the **Any Linux Distro** instructions, but *don't run the install script*. **With Xfce**, just open the extracted folder and double-click **bash silentcast**. With other desktops, run from the terminal from within the extracted folder. That's it! Nothing will be copied into your system files and deleting the extracted folder will completely remove it from your system.

I wasn't happy with either of these answers so I wrote my own: [Silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/#silentcast).

If anything doesn't work for you, please file a bug at [Silentcast Issues](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/issues)

Notice there's a stop icon [image: stop1.png] in the Notificaton Area before I even start Silentcast, then a 2nd stop icon [image: stop2.png] appears when recording begins. That's because I already had Silentcast running to make these animated gifs of how to use Silentcast. Silentcast 1 keeps going after I stop Silentcast 2.

#### Fullscreen: How to use Silentcast to record Gimp

[image: Fullscreen]

#### Transparent: How to use Silentcast to record 2 windows

[image: Transparent]

#### Interior: How to use Silentcast to only record the drawing

[image: Interior]

#### Entirety: How to use Silentcast to record 1 window

[image: Entirety]

#### Installation

... (skipping over some stuff - in the full README, this includes a list of dependencies and distro specific instructions for installing them)

- **Any Linux Distro Full Install Without Root Access**

  - Install missing dependencies (see the *Dependencies* table and *Installing Dependencies by Distro* above)
  - Download a version of Silentcast:

    - Should always work as intended: [Download Latest Release of Silentcast from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/releases/latest)
    - Most likely working right: [Download Silentcast master.zip from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/archive/master.zip)
    - Probably broken when in active development, otherwise the same as master: [Download Silentcast next.zip from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/archive/next.zip)
  - Extract. Then, from a terminal, `cd` into the extracted directory and `./no_root_install` **Uninstall** instructions are provided in the output of the *no_root_install* script. You can also see them in the comments to the launcher. See options with `./no_root_install -h`. If installed to the default location, **uninstall** with the following commands: `rm -r ~/.silentcast` and `rm ~/.local/share/applications/no_root_silentcast.desktop`
  - See what version you've got with `silentcast -v`. [Check for a newer version](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/releases/latest
- **Any Linux Distro Full Install**

  - Install missing dependencies (see the *Dependencies* table and *Installing Dependencies by Distro* above)
  - Download a version of Silentcast:

    - Should always work as intended: [Download Latest Release of Silentcast from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/releases/latest)
    - Most likely working right: [Download Silentcast master.zip from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/archive/master.zip)
    - Probably broken when in active development, otherwise the same as master: [Downlad Silentcast next.zip from github.com](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/archive/next.zip)
  - Extract. Then, from a terminal, `cd` into the extracted directory and `sudo ./install` **Uninstall** instructions are the same replacing *install* with *uninstall*. The **install** (or **uninstall**) bash script just copies (or deletes) files. You may want to edit them if your distro puts files in unusual places.
  - See what version you've got with `silentcast -v`. [Check for a newer version](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/releases/latest)

...(see full README for how to install dependencies for your distro)

- **Arch Linux Full Install**

  - Use an AUR helper, like `yaourt -S silentcast`. This will automatically install the latest release and missing dependencies. Keep your install up to date the usual way with your AUR helper, like `yaourt -Syua`. **Uninstall** with `sudo pacman -R silentcast`
  - Without an AUR helper, just [Download silentcast.tar.gz from aur.archlinux.org](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/si/silentcast/silentcast.tar.gz), extract, and do `makepkg -si` from the extracted directory. This will do exactly the same thing as an AUR helper would do for installation, but you will have to keep track of updates yourself. **Uninstall** with `sudo pacman -R silentcast`
- **Ubuntu Linux Full Install**

  - For 14.04 and 12.04 run the following commands to install Silentcast (for older versions of Ubuntu follow the "Any Linux Distro" instructions below):

    ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sethj/silentcast  
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install silentcast
    ```

    Or run the following, condensed, command:

    ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sethj/silentcast && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install silentcast
    ```

    - **Uninstall**
      Run `sudo apt-get remove silentcast`. You can then remove the PPAs with `sudo add-apt-repository -r` like so:

      ```
      sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:sethj/silentcast && sudo apt-get update
      ```

#### Launch Methods

- Menu Hierarchy

  - Graphics -> Silentcast
  - Multimedia -> Silentcast
- Search Box Terms

  - silentcast
  - screencast
  - record
  - gif
  - (and other things will work too)
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

  - silentcast
- Terminal

  - silentcast

Find *Silentcast* in the menu under either *Graphics* or *Multimedia*, type *silentcast* into the search box, or *<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> silentcast*. It can also be run from a terminal as *silentcast*.

Comment: Whoa. That looks epic. I'll give it a poke later and see if we can't fix up those links

Comment: Thank you - you've already given me 11 points just from the upvote I guess. I can't remember though, is that enough for me to add more links? Well, I just did. So yes - now I can add more to my answer.

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to work on fedora 20/KDE  - what would be the appropriate place for a bug report?

Comment: Since my source is on github, that would be the best place to file a bug report: [Silentcast Issues](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/issues)

Comment: I have only tested it on my own system - Xfce on Arch Linux. I would expect it to run on KDE though. It's just bash scripts. Either I missed something in the dependencies I listed in the README.md, or it might require a special version of ffmpeg that I happen to have. I would like to work it out, so please do file a bug report. Thanks You.

Comment: Small mistake on my part. `sudo yum install ffmpeg yad xdotool xorg-xwininfo wmctrl python-gobject python-cairo xdg-utils ImageMagick` should pull in all the deps on fedora. I seemed to have forgotten ImageMagik. I like this enough to toss it a 50 rep bounty, which I'll award once the waiting period is over ;)

Comment: You've made me very happy. As far as I know, this is the first software I've created that is being enthusiastically used by someone other than myself. I'm surprised something similar wasn't already done because all I did was give already existing command line tools a GUI using yad and some python code I found with google.

Comment: This is ridiculously awesome. I just found two wonderful tools to play with today.

Comment: It doesn't work in Unity, but that is Unity's fault (it is really strict about indicators). I think I might be able to come up with a patch however. Really awesome in Xubuntu though!

Comment: I've added instructions to the README.md for installing Ubuntu dependencies.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you mentioned in the comments of another answer that you might want to do screen capture on a RPi.  Have you tried this solution on the RPi and if so, can you comment on how well it works?

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid - I need to.

Comment: I cannot find silentcast launcher after the installation.

Comment: Can you provide details on your install? Distribution, desktop, from a package manager, or what?

Answer (score 22):

One possible solution is [byzanz](https://github.com/GNOME/byzanz) if you don’t mind using the CLI. Byznaz run on  Ubuntu and I didn’t test it on different Linux distributions. I tested it only on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

It's a rather rudimentary screen recorder with limited options.

[image: byzanz]

Byzanz records GIF's and runs in a terminal only.
It is not included in Ubuntu repositories and  it can be only installed through a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byzanz).

To install use this commands

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/byzanz
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install byzanz
```

Man pages:

```
Usage:

  byzanz-record [OPTION...] record your current desktop session

Help Options:
  -?, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

GTK+ Options
  --class=CLASS            Program class as used by the window manager
  --name=NAME              Program name as used by the window manager
  --gtk-module=MODULES     Load additional GTK+ modules
  --g-fatal-warnings       Make all warnings fatal

Application Options:
  -d, --duration=SECS      Duration of animation (default: 10 seconds)
  --delay=SECS             Delay before start (default: 1 second)
  -c, --cursor             Record mouse cursor
  -a, --audio              Record audio
  -x, --x=PIXEL            X coordinate of rectangle to record
  -y, --y=PIXEL            Y coordinate of rectangle to record
  -w, --width=PIXEL        Width of recording rectangle
  -h, --height=PIXEL       Height of recording rectangle
  -v, --verbose            Be verbose
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

Comment: I suppose its close enough. Telling it *which* pixel ranges to record seem unnecessarily troublesome. That said, barring a better answer, I'd be unfair if I didn't select this as the correct one.

Comment: Actually there is a tool with lets say better screen recording options and nice GUI but so far I were not able to save it in GIF. Although recording screen or part of screen in some other format is breeze.

Comment: you have to type in the location and size? *cringe*

Comment: There is a RPM build which seems to be available from the default Fedora repos as well - RPMs can also be found [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=byzanz)

Comment: You can run [xrectsel](https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel) and drag your mouse to get the location and size of the desired recangle, and then use those numbers to run byzanz.

Comment: Byzanz is included in Universe in 16.04. I wouldn't call it rudimentary as well, because current version seems to be pretty useful

Comment: Question was originally for 12.04. at time Byzantine was far away from what is now.

Answer (score 11):

LICEcap works on Linux with Wine -- check it out:

[image: Scrolling through the LICEcap webpage]

This is on Arch Linux, 64-bit and wine 1.7.18.

Comment: Oh, I'm aware of this - It isn't a wrong answer, but I may want to run it on non x86 architectures, say on a raspberry pi, and wine is pretty heavy, comparatively - hence my preference for a native option

Comment: Also the cursor doesn't appear if the licecap window isn't focused..

Answer (score 10):

You could take a look at [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) too.

Peek is a simple tool that lets you record a section of your screen and save it as an animated GIF image.

**Peek screenshot:**
[image: Peek screenshot]

**Peek recording:**

[image: Peek recording]

Peek requires FFmpeg + ImageMagick to be installed and currently only works with X11 and is targeted at GNOME 3 (thus it should work even in Unity so long as you don’t have Locally Integrated Menus enabled).

Comment: This demands >700 MByte in download and 2.5 gigs of disk space...?!?

Answer (score 2):

I Haven't seen it mentioned here, so try Scrot.

[image: Scrot In Synaptic Package Manager]

It's part of my Ubuntu packages so should be in universe at the least without PPA's

I Have zero experience in using it, but I'll generally go with a distro package managed version over a third party ppa or repository 90% of the time for such software.

Comment: Does it do *animated* gifs? I'm pretty sure scrot does *static* screenshots from the command line. It has its uses, but I'm not convinced its the right tool here

Comment: I Have no clue what it does, but I'm pretty sure with a bash script you could make it collect multiple images, then put them all into an animated gif or png. It was just meant to be another option.

Comment: I don't think scrot records gifs

Comment: Perhaps this is a language barrier. I suggested recording separate images. Those images would (implicit separate later author action) be what the author converts to a gif.

Answer (score 1):

I use
1. Byznaz for recording

```
sudo apt-get install byzanz #ubuntu
dnf install byzanz #fedora
```

2. python-xrectsel for area selection

```
pip install python-xrectsel
```