# Looking for software to record small videos as .gif/ .webm for the web?

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I'm looking for software that can record videos for the web, for example for on Stackoverflow answers and my website.

It would be fantastic if there was a screen-recorder that was made for this purpose, something that outputs to .gif and .webm. If there is nothing like it, normal recording software with the following features would be great.

- Support for at least Windows, it's better if it also supports Linux
- Record videos
- Follow mouse and specify the size of the screen to be recorded, this is a must
- Preferably able to output to both gif and .webm, can do without
- Audio support not needed

Comment: Here are some solutions for Windows and OSX: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/make-a-gif-video

Comment: Here is the solution for Linux Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast

Comment: For Linux, see the question: [Linux-based alternative to LICEcap](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/710/60)